# How to create a dynamic form with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

I currently have a basic form where the user can submit a paragraph of text. However, I want them to be able to choose either to paste their paragraph or to instead upload a file. In essence, this choice will determine which input field shows. Is there a mechanism to do this?

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [quill](https://quilljs.com) if you are looking for text editor like in most content management website